# In Swift, why won't this .reduce() add all values together? Only printing first number in array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to coding and am working on an iOS app that I can basically enter my daily tips (at my job) and it gets added to each respective day (basically a calculator synced with a calendar).  Right now, I'm just trying to get multiple tips and added up to get a grand total.  The steps are basically: 1. enter tip amount with buttons; 2. hit "add today"; 3. screen changes to a "grand total" which SHOULD display the sum of all values in array.

The problem is, while the console shows every new value is added to the array, they are not being added together and the console continues to simply print the first value.  The "grand total" seems to reflect that as well, and only prints the first value.  Any help would be great!  I'll post the whole code below:

```
import UIKit

class CalcScreen: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tipAmount: UILabel!
    
    var tipArray: [Int] = []
    
    lazy var tipArrayTotal = tipArray.reduce(0, +)
    
    public var tip: Int = 0
    
    let vc = TipTotalView(nibName: "TipTotalView", bundle: nil)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    func clearTip() {
        tip = 0
        tipAmount.text = String(tip)
    }
    
    func addToTip (value: Int) {
        tip = tip * 10 + value
        tipAmount.text = String(tip)
        tipArray.append(value)
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func zero(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 0)
    }
    
    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: Any) {
        clearTip()
    }
    
    @IBAction func one(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 1)
    }
    
    @IBAction func two(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 2)
    }
    
    @IBAction func three(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 3)
    }
    
    @IBAction func four(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 4)
    }
    
    @IBAction func five(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 5)
    }
    
    @IBAction func six(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 6)
    }
    
    @IBAction func seven(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 7)
    }
    
    @IBAction func eight(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 8)
    }
    
    @IBAction func nine(_ sender: Any) {
        addToTip(value: 9)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func addToday(_ sender: Any) {
        
        vc.totalTip?.text = String(tipArrayTotal)
        clearTip()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        print(tipArray)
        print(tipArrayTotal)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func changeDate(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `lazy`. A lazy var is a stored property that is only calculated, and stored, the first time it is accessed. This is why it never changes after the first access.

In your case you want a computed property.

```
var tipArrayTotal: Int {
    return tipArray.reduce(0, +)
}
```

Now it will be calculated every time you access it. So if you reference the property multiple times in one method you should change the code to call it once and store it in a local variable and then reference that variable in the rest of the method.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks a ton.  Now there's a weird thing happening where the first time I enter a value (and seems to be ONLY the first time) the totalTip UILabel displays 0.  After there's more than one value in the array, it will display the sum.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The rest of your code makes little sense. If you enter 1, 2, and 3, then `tip` equals 123 but the array has 1, 2, and 3 in it for a total of 6. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: I actually had JUST realized what you're mentioning when I implemented your initial advice.  Changed all buttons to `String`, which then gets converted to `Int` to be entered into the array.  UILabel still displays 0 on the first tip entered, however.

Comment: FWIW, @cjshhi, `var tipArrayTotal: Int { tipArray.reduce(0, +) }` also works…